# Array destructuring to number type

Tags: javascript, arrays, casting, type-conversion

I have a string like:

```
const coordonate = 'a5';
```

I want to split the letter that will be transformed latter into a number which represents the column and the <5> which represents the row.

For this I do something like this:

```
[columnLetter, row] = coordinate.split('');

column = getColumnByLetter(columnLetter); // Returns a number.
```

....

```
result = doSomethingWithNumbers(column, row); // The problem is row is a String.
```

I could do:

```
result = doSomethingWithNumbers(column, Number(row));
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to retrieve directly row as number...
Something like:

```
[columnLetter, Number(row)] = coordinate.split('');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reassign the variable:

```js
const coord = 'A5'

let [ col, row ] = coord.split('')
row = Number(row)

console.log(typeof col, col);
console.log(typeof row, row);
```

Or map the values:

```js
const coord = 'A5'

const [col, row] = coord.split('').map(i => +i || i)

console.log(typeof col, col);
console.log(typeof row, row);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check the value with `isNaN` and take numbers or strings for `NaN` values.

```js
var string = 'a5',
    [row, col] = string.split('').map(v => isNaN(v) ? v : +v);
    

console.log(typeof row, row);
console.log(typeof col, col);
```

Comment: you could also use the index to convert to a number, so `.map((v,i)=>i?+v:v)` should work too

Comment: i was thinking about before this comes to mind. i find this solution more generic.

Comment: This is a nice idea to map it before destructoring, but I was thinking if the destructoring itself can do that ?? Like, to receive it directly as expected...

Comment: there is no other operation possible at the LHS's destructuring than assignment or further destructuring. (LHS = left hand side)

Answer (score 0):

You could use map function.

```js
const coordinate = 'a5'; 
[columnLetter,row] = coordinate.split('').map((item) => typeof item == 'number' ? Number(item) : item);
console.log(columnLetter, row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to do that in one line:

```
doSomethingWithNumbers(coordinate[0], Number(coordinate[1]))
```

Comment: I don't want to cast it all the time where I use it, but I was wondering more about the idea than the solution of this problem... (which can be trivial)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to make an array from your coordinates string, where each character is coerced to a number or left as a string:

```js
const coordinate = 'a5';
[columnLetter, row] = Array.from(coordinate, c => +c || c); // [str: 'a', num: 5]

console.log(typeof columnLetter, typeof row);
```